# In jQuery Mobile, how do I stop list items being cut off with ellipses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have this list:

```
<ul id="linksList"
    data-role="listview"
    data-inset="true"
    data-filter="true">
    <!-- Dynamic contents! -->
</ul>
```

It gets its data from a local XML file (RSS feed). All I want is for the titles to either wrap down or show more of the title within the buttons, as I have probably two thirds of the button left to fill with text.

**[Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3SOK.jpg)**

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What else do you want? i shall edit with it

Comment: Whatever it would take to rebuild your problem from scratch. Best if you could produce a working problem on jsfiddle.

Comment: The problem is a fairly common one where jQuery Mobile's base CSS strong-arms the list items into overflowing into ellipses. I've edited the OP with a bit more information on the subject, but a quick test in Firebug shows that my solution below should fix things.

Comment: Hi dave, i'm quite the novice to be honest with you. When putting your fix into a css file how would i reference my list? i.e would i just use the id? as i know there are special identifiers for jqms listviews and such

Answer (score 4):

You need to override the jQuery Mobile default of showing ellipsis for the elements you want to have wrap:

```
overflow:hidden;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

becomes:

```
overflow: visible;
text-overflow: clip;
white-space: normal;
```

I recommend doing this on an as-needed basis using your own classes rather than modifying the base code.

Comment: Hi dave, i'm quite the novice to be honest with you. When putting your fix into a css file how would i reference my list? i.e would i just use the id? as i know there are special identifiers for jqms listviews and such

Comment: On [another SE topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9254902/1181955), there's a code snippet that you can use as a class on your list to make it kill the ellipses. I think that user's code snippet will be more effective than any advice I lend at the moment.

Comment: it seems like no matter what i do nothing affects either of the listviews i have. i have tried the other topic link you suggested also did not affect either of the lists. My stylesheet is linked in after the jqm one would it matter if it is a cdn over a local copy? would it matter if it is a thumbnail listview?

Answer (score 3):

I didn't have to change text-overflow. also.. I added in the class names.  Copy and paste the following:

```
.ui-li-heading, .ui-li-desc { 
  overflow: visible; 
  white-space: normal; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ellipses are caused by jQuery mobile setting widths and setting the overflow to ellipses. You would need to go into the CSS on the item and set the margins to use less space.