# how to make the field change with the screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a mobile website. Inside it I've got an image and description. Everything is fine and the website changes itself if using phone or tablet or laptop, but I have one problem. For the description in small devices, it will truncate the text with "..." if the text is too long. How can I make it continue onto the next line?

**Code**

```
<body> 

    <div data-role="page" id="page" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="content" >
    </div>
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <?php do { ?>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="../d/p/<?php echo $row_productDaata['strImage']; ?>" alt=""/>
                <p style="font-size:18px"><?php echo $row_productDaata['strProductName']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $row_productDaata['dblP']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $row_productDaata['strdescription']; ?></p> // here is the problem 

            </a></li>
        <?php } while ($row_productDaata = mysql_fetch_assoc($productDaata)); ?>
    </ul>
    <div data-role="footer" >
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of PHP code you really need to provide your CSS styles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep this <p> from getting clipped when it exceeds the width of the page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799980/how-to-keep-this-p-from-getting-clipped-when-it-exceeds-the-width-of-the-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using jQuery Mobile. This has already been answered: [How to keep this <p> from getting clipped when it exceeds the width of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799980/how-to-keep-this-p-from-getting-clipped-when-it-exceeds-the-width-of-the-page)

Comment: thank you so much , i guess this is the ans , but i cant found the p tag text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap; ,

inside my Jquery Mobile to change it